# Power BI: How do I sum a row into two other rows?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I have a table where one product should be included in the sum of two other product categories. The way I currently have it set up, it's separated.

In the picture, the "11 Alcohol Sales" should not be a row but instead should be included in the "Light Alcohol & Ethoxylate Sales" and also the "1/3/5 Alcohol & Ethoxylate Sales.

[image: Current Table]

I tried creating measures but when I do so, I am not able to keep a table format like I currently have and it makes the table much more complicated.

I got this far by making a calculated column that I used as the row headings in my table. The issue is the common product N11 and L11 should be included in both Light Alcohols and 1/3/5 Alcohols.

Any advice on a better way to sum these values?

[image: Calculated Column]

Comment: Overlapping categories makes for quite the headache if you're trying to use them in the same visual. Is this the case or do you have different categories for different visuals?

Comment: Aggregating data like this won't work with calculated columns. Treating the data in power query or using a measure would a better fit. Could you share a sample pbi?